# How to setup AndroidAnnotations on android studio?

Tags: android, android-annotations

I did go to Project Structure ->app>Dependencies-> add library->annotations

And when I put @EActivity(R.layout.activity_main) over the main activity what I can do is to create an annotations..but it can not do anything with  (R.layout.activity_main).

Androud Studio 2.1.2

Comment: I assume, you are talking about AndroidAnnotations. Just take a look at their documentation. They have a pretty thorough guide for Android Studio and Gradle: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Configuration

Comment: Thank you, really helped me out!:)

Answer (score 2):

Good way is to add your Annotation through Gradle. Then you are able to import and edit it.

Here you have [link](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle) for official AndroidAnnotation documentation

And here is my working gradle configuration:
**build.gradle (Projec:ProjectName)**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "example.project"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
def AAVersion = "4.5.0-SNAPSHOT" // change this to your desired version, for example the latest stable: 4.4.0
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in file app/build.gradle add to dependencies :

```
annotationProcessor 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.4.0'
implementation 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.4.0'
```

full file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.doodkin.svetacalculator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    annotationProcessor 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.4.0'
    implementation 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

then, for example, need to add @EActivity to an activity

```
package com.doodkin.svetacalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

@EActivity // need to add this
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @ViewById // example use this
    public EditText screen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        screen.setText("test");
    }
}
```

then after adding @EActivity to an activity. need to modify its class name in app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml to add an underscore to end of the name of the class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.doodkin.svetacalculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity_">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample - just build.gradle(app):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'

dependencies {
  apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
  compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  // other dependencies
}

apt {
  arguments {
    androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    resourcePackageName 'myfull.packagename'
  }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1'
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'build/generated/source/apt/${variant.dirName}']
      resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
      res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }
  }
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
  }
  productFlavors {}
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}
```